# Flutter Project Build Failure

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build, build.gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/ VS Code Projects /zero_app/android/app/build.gradle' line: 26
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'kotlin-android'.
> Extension with name 'android' does not exist. Currently registered extension names: [ext, googleServices, kotlin, kotlinTestRegistry]

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 600ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Build.Gradle :

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.scriptlk.zero_app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    //implementation platform('com.google.firebase: firebase:firebase-bom:26.8.0')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code snippet.

Android Studio modifies your build.gradle adding apply plugin: 'kotlin-android' above apply plugin: 'com.android.application'. Just move the Kotlin line below the Android one and Gradle will run smoothly. It should look like this example:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

Comment: I tried this. But I still get the same Issue.